# How do I move the form up to an image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I would like to shift the form up to the image. However, I have tried but I still could not shift the whole form up.

Below is the html and css codes:

```css
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}

/* Encounter issues here, please take a look at the second image*/
.formcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600.jpg" class="body">
        <h2> Registration </h2>
   
    <div class="formcontainer">
        <form action>
            <label for="name">Name :</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter your name"></input>
            <br>
            <label for="age">Age :</label> <br>
            <input type="number" name="age" min="1"></input>
            <br>
            <label for="gender">Gender :</label> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
            <br>
            <label for="membertype">Types of membership :</label> <br>
    
            <select name="type">
                <option value="OneYr">1 Year</option>
                <option value="FiveYr" selected>5 Years</option>
                <option value="LifeTime">Life Time</option>
            </select>
        
            <br>
            <br/>
            
            <label for="interests">Interests :</label>
            <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Bike"> Travel<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Food"> Food<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Shopping"> Shopping<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Cars"> Cars<br>
            </br>
            
            <input type ="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

After I have tried using the above .formcontainer css codes:
[image]

Comment: use your image as a `background-image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your image in `.container` style not using `img` tag.

```
.container{
  background-image: url("../img/gym.jpg");
}
```

See the Snippet below:

```css
.container{
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dbsg.png");
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <img src="../img/gym.jpg" class="body">
        <h2> Registration </h2>
   
    <div class="formcontainer">
        <form action>
            <label for="name">Name :</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter your name"></input>
            <br>
            <label for="age">Age :</label> <br>
            <input type="number" name="age" min="1"></input>
            <br>
            <label for="gender">Gender :</label> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
            <br>
            <label for="membertype">Types of membership :</label> <br>
    
            <select name="type">
                <option value="OneYr">1 Year</option>
                <option value="FiveYr" selected>5 Years</option>
                <option value="LifeTime">Life Time</option>
            </select>
        
            <br>
            <br/>
            
            <label for="interests">Interests :</label>
            <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Bike"> Travel<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Food"> Food<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Shopping"> Shopping<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Cars"> Cars<br>
            </br>
            
            <input type ="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a UI expert, but adding the image as background to the parent-div should do.

```css
.container {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/xJCmfmT/test3.jpg");
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in couple of ways as far as I know.

1. set the image as parent div (**container** here) background using

   ```
   .container {
       background-image: url(IMAGE_URL);
   }
   ```
2. set position of **formcontainer** as *absolute*

   ```
   .formcontainer {
       position: absolute;
   }
   ```